# PHP preg_replace not working as intended

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace **/admin** and **\admin** from the following two strings:

```
F:\dev\htdocs\cms\admin
http://localhost/cms/admin
```

Using the following regular expression in **preg_replace**:

```
/[\/\\][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/i
```

1) From the first string it just replaces **admin** where as it should replace **\admin**

2) From the second string it replaces every thing except **http:** where as it should replace only **/admin**

I have checked this expression on http://regexpal.com/ and it works perfect there but not in PHP.

Any idea?

> Note that the last part of each string **admin** is not fixed, it can
>   be any user selected value and thats why I have used [a-zA-Z0-9_-]* in
>   regular expression.

Comment: In the first bracket, i require either a \ or / but only one at a time

Comment: [You regex works](http://regex101.com/r/hK1pI5).

Comment: @glavic yes it works but not in PHP preg_replace. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original regular expression should be `/[\/\\][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/i`, but since you need to escape the backslashes in string declarations as well, each backslash must be expressed with `\\` -- 4 backslashes in total.

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> Single and double quoted PHP strings have special meaning of backslash. Thus if \ has to be matched with a regular expression `\\`, then `"\\\\"` or `'\\\\'` must be used in PHP code.

So, your `preg_replace()` statement should look like:

```
echo preg_replace('/[\/\\\\][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/i', '', $str);
```

Your regex can be improved as follows:

```
echo preg_replace('~[/\\\\][\w-]*$~', '', $str);
```

Here, `\w` matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You can also avoid having to escape the forward slash `/` by using a different delimiter -- I've used `~` above.

Comment: Imho that's only right for patterns in double-quotes. Using single-quotes 3 backslashes should be fine, why not? E.g. `echo preg_replace('/(\\\)([\\\])/', '\1_\2_', "\\\\");`

Comment: @AmalMurali: since you used `\w` escape sequence, you don't need `/i` modifier anymore.

Comment: @Jonny5: That works, too, but requires changing the OP's original regex.  Since `\]` is an invalid escape sequence, it will remain as it is, and that's probably why it works (although I'm not too sure about it).

Comment: Assuming you have a string `\test`, and want to replace `\t` : `"~\\\t~"` will NOT work, whereas `"~\\\\t~"` and `'~\\\t~'` will work. Imho the escape level for escaping a backslash when using single-quoted pattern is 1 level less.

Answer (score 0):

```
[\/\\\][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/i
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/4Tz0M8)